# What to do with face descriptors of the same person from multiple photos?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, face-recognition, dlib

Using neural networks for face recognition, the network will generate a "face descriptor" that is, depending on the network of course, often a 128D vector that describes a face ("In general, if two face descriptor vectors have a Euclidean between them less than 0.6 then they are from the same person, otherwise they are from different people." <sup>[1](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/face_recognition.py#L102)</sup>).

I am trying to develop a photographs application that features face recognition, although I do not know how to store the face descriptor of a person. The question is **NOT** how to serialize them, but when there are hundreds of different photos of the same person, yet each yielding a different face descriptor (because the angle, lighting and etc. are different), how to choose which one to store? Presumably, there should be a way to "improve" the descriptors as more and more photos are processed, **without** training the neural network.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I asked Adam Geitgey, author of the [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) library for Python, and he answered:

> There's a few ways to approach this:
>
> 1. You could just keep one face encoding per person. But people tend to change over time, etc. So this might not give you the best accuracy with a large image set.
> 2. You could take all face encodings for each person and train a classifier that decides which person is which for new face encodings. You could use an SVM classifier or even something simple like a linear classifier. This is the strategy that [OpenFace](http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/) uses. The downside is you have to train new classifiers repeatedly as new data is added and verified by the user.
> 3. A more clever approach is to use a clustering algorithm like [Chinese Whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Whispers_(clustering_method)). The idea is that each face encoding is a node in a graph data structure. The clustering algorithm automatically sorts the nodes so that the closest-distance nodes get clustered and can be assumed to be the same person. There's a [dlib example program](http://dlib.net/dnn_face_recognition_ex.cpp.html) (written in C++) that demonstrates this.